# CaptureElement as an ellipse shape

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, photo, win-universal-app

In Windows (Phone) 8.1 Runtime, CaptureElement has substituted VideoBrush for previewing stream from camera device. I would like to show the preview in an ellipse shape. Previosuly I was doing it by setting the VideoBrush source in the Ellipse.Fill property. I cannot do it with the CaptureElement (Ellipse.Fill must be a Brush). Is there any other way I can shape CaptureElement into a Circle?

How did it look like in Windows Phone 8.0:

```
<Ellipse>
 <Ellipse.Fill>
   <VideoBrush x:Name="viewfinderBrush" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
 </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

and then I was setting the source with my PhotoCaptureDevice

```
viewfinderBrush.SetSource(_proCameraDevice);
```

Now I have    Ellipse and     CaptureElement (which is square control by default). As I said - CaptureElement cannot be set as the Ellipse.Fill property

Comment: It's helpful for others if you show your XAML or code.

Comment: code added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no direct way to do this. The Windows Runtime doesn't have anything analagous to VideoBrush and no non-rectangular clipping.

What you can do is to display the preview in a rectangular window but cover it with an opaque mask with your ellipse cut out of it. Something approximating the following (but with your app's sizing, naming, etc.)

```
    <CaptureElement />
    <Path Fill="{ThemeResource MyOpaqueBackgroundBrush}">
        <Path.Data>
            <GeometryGroup>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0 300,300" />
                <EllipseGeometry Center="150,150" RadiusX="100" RadiusY="100" />
            </GeometryGroup>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is not the result I was expecting so I guess I will have to resign from Universal App and stick to Silverlight for WP.